# How to set domain with a many2one

Tags: python, odoo

I have a many2one that links to event.event called xx_event_id. In event.event I made a link to xx_weeks that is a separate model that keeps a list of weeks. Then the name of those weeks also links to a model called xx_week_name.

I'm trying to make a domain on xx_week_name. When I select an event I only want it to show the week names that are in the event.

So my xml looks like this:

```
<field name="xx_week_name" domain="[('id', 'in', xx_event_id.xx_weeks.name)]"/>
```

Yet it gives an error:

```
Uncaught Error: AttributeError: object has no attribute 'xx_weeks'
```

Answer (score 0):

The domain is implemented in the javascript side and over there you cannot use Odoo's smart records (the 'dot' notation).

What you can do if you want to set a domain using a relational field is the following:

1) Declare a related field that will "pull" the name as a string from your relational field
week_name = fields.Char(related='xx_event_id.xx_weeks.name')

2) Insert that field in your view as invisible. In that way it will not change our view and we can still have access to it.

3) Change the filter in your relational field

That should work, but there is a chance that you have made a logical error in your domain. You check for `[('id', 'in', xx_event_id.xx_weeks.name)]` possibly you want something different there such as `[('id', 'in', xx_event_id.xx_weeks.name)]` If so modify the example above accordingly.